# React Application Serving 404 Component Instead of Index on Both Local and GitHub Pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router, github-pages

I am working on a React application and facing an issue where the application is showing the 404 error component instead of the index component. This is happening both on my local development server as well as when the application is deployed to GitHub Pages.

My code is available on GitHub: [arch-studio-multipage-website repository](https://github.com/AzureCloud9/arch-studio-multipage-website).

Here is my routing setup in `App.js`:

```js
import { createBrowserRouter, Route, createRoutesFromElements, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import RootLayout from "./layout/RootLayout";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import NotFound from "./pages/NotFound";

const router = createBrowserRouter({
  basename: '/arch-studio-multipage-website',
  routes: createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Route>
  )
});

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cloned your repo and noticed a couple different things going on:

1. You need to install `react-router-dom` to the project itself via `npm i react-router-dom`
2. You're passing arguments to `createBrowserRouter` incorrectly. It takes a list of routes as the first parameter and options second. I was able to get it working correctly by changing it to this:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path="/" element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
    </Route>
  ),
  {
    basename: "/arch-studio-multipage-website",
  }
);
```

Comment: my localhost is working perfectly now, I'm still experiencing the same issue with the NotFound component being displayed on GitHub Pages

Comment: Did you re-run your deploy job? If this is the repo: https://github.com/AzureCloud9/arch-studio-multipage-website/actions - the last deploy job was 4 hours ago. Also, why did you unmark my response as an answer when I responded before the other person?

Comment: hi, I thought I could like accept both answers, but then I noticed it yours was gone. I guess I forgot to like it again sorry. but back to the issue. I just redeploy it via GitHub desktop, but it still shows the same thing.

Comment: @AzureCloud I looked at your latest actions and it appears to be deploying the `gh-pages` branch which does not include your latest changes. You need to merge `main` back into it and push: `git checkout main`, `git pull`, `git checkout gh-pages`, `git merge main`, `git push -u origin gh-pages`.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you're using `createBrowserRouter` incorrectly. According to the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/create-browser-router), there should be two arguments - the first one should be an array of routes (in your case, returned by `createRoutesFromElements` and the second argument should be an object with options (in your case, `basename`).

Here is a fixed `router` object:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path='/' element={<RootLayout />}>
      <Route index element={<Home />} />
      <Route path='*' element={<NotFound />} />
    </Route>
  ),
  {
    basename: '/arch-studio-multipage-website',
  }
);
```

To avoid such errors in the future, I recommend using TypeScript - in this case, TypeScript should be able to detect that the types of the arguments are incorrect and point you to the solution.

Also, `react-router-dom` is missing from the dependencies in your `package.json` - you've probably installed is globally instead of inside the project. Run `npm install react-router-dom` inside this project's directory to fix that.

Comment: my localhost is working perfectly now, I'm still experiencing the same issue with the NotFound component being displayed on GitHub Pages